# Not returning array values

Tags: c

```
// function to convert decimal to binary 
int *decToBinary(int n) 
{ 
    // array to store binary number 
    static int *binNum; //, array_bin[31]; 

    //printf("number as input%d\n",n);
    int dec_num = n;

    // counter for binary array 
    int i = 0 ,k ,j ; 
    if (n == 0)
    {
     binNum[i] = 0; 
        //n = n / 2; 
        i++; 
    }
    while (n != 0) { 
        // storing remainder in binary array 
        binNum[i] = n % 2; 
            n = n / 2; 
           i++; 
    } 
     //int j;
    // printing binary array in reverse order 
    for (int j = i - 1 ; j >= 0 ; j--)
        if (i>0)
        {//printf ("dectobin for loop%d",j);
       //printf("The binary equivalent of %d is %d. %d %d\n", dec_num, binNum[j],j,i);
       i--; }
       return binNum;
    }
```

I have written a function to obtain decimal to binary notation .This set of code does not return all the array values.The function get a decimal value as input and return a pointer to the array containing the binary values.However , the array returned doesnot print all the values.

Comment: Where are you allocating the array?

Comment: `binNum` points to nothing. Undefined behavior.

Comment: Your creating a pointer `static int *binNum;` but how are you pointing it to `array_bin[31]` there is no `array_bin[31]` in your function? Is it global?

Comment: Also your function only excepts an `int`, so you cannot be sending in the array

Comment: Please save us a lot of asking for clarification on your question by posting a [mcve].  Then we can effectively help you

Comment: the array is of type int

Comment: Which array? There is no array in the code.

Comment: regarding: `static int *binNum;` is only declares a pointer to `int` is does not allocate an array.  Suggest: `static int binNum[32];